# How can multiple threads have the same thread ID?

Tags: c, multithreading, ubuntu, unix, process

I've got a question: can multiple threads have the same thread_id? (Of course not.) But my code is doing so. How is this possible?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<pthread.h>
#include<sys/types.h>

void* message(void* var){
    int t = (int)var;


    printf("\n%d- Hi I'm thread ID=%lu\n",t+1,(int unsigned long)pthread_self());
}

int main(void){
    pthread_t threads[10];
    int report[10];
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
        report[i] = pthread_create(&threads[i],NULL,message,(void*)i);
        pthread_join(threads[i],NULL);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

My code at (Ubuntu 17.04) showing this result

```
1- Hi I'm thread ID=3076250432

2- Hi I'm thread ID=3076250432

3- Hi I'm thread ID=3076250432

4- Hi I'm thread ID=3076250432

5- Hi I'm thread ID=3076250432

6- Hi I'm thread ID=3076250432

7- Hi I'm thread ID=3076250432

8- Hi I'm thread ID=3076250432

9- Hi I'm thread ID=3076250432

10- Hi I'm thread ID=3076250432
```

Comment: Thread IDs can be recycled. Your code is starting a thread and waiting for it to finish. There are never more then one (apart from the main-thread) running. Hence, you get the same ID.

Comment: Well you're waiting for each newly-created thread to stop before starting the next one. Have you tried changing your code to actually run all the threads in parallel, by having two loops, one to start threads and one to join them?

Comment: `pthread_create(&x, NULL, y, z); pthread_join(x, NULL);` is equivalent to `y(z)` except much, much slower.

Comment: y(z) means ? creating process inside of other??

Comment: @WaseemAhmadNaeem In your code `x` is `threads[i]`, `y` is `message` and `z` is `(void *)i`, so `y(z)` is `message((void *)i)`

Comment: What I mean is that joining a thread just after creating it is just a waste of time, it's better to not create the thread at all. (This pattern is something I actually see quite often in questions about threads on stackoverflow).

Comment: Ohh Thanks @Art for explanation. I'm thankful

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
    report[i] = pthread_create(&threads[i],NULL,message,(void*)i);
    pthread_join(threads[i],NULL);
}
```

You're creating a thread and then immediately joining it, waiting for it to finish. This causes the ten threads to be created sequentially rather than in parallel, allowing their IDs to be recycled.

If you create all ten threads before joining on them you'll see different IDs.

```
for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
    report[i] = pthread_create(&threads[i],NULL,message,(void*)i);
}

for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
    pthread_join(threads[i],NULL);
}
```

Comment: Can the IDs be reused prior to `pthread_join()` being called?

Comment: No, the `pthread_t` pointer ('ID') cannot be reused prior to calling `pthread_join()`, as otherwise `pthread_join()` does not know for which thread to wait, as the `pthread_t` pointer is the only way of identifying the thread.